# google big query: export table to own bucket results in unexpected error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'am stuck trying to export a table to my google cloud storage bucket.

Example job id: job_0463426872a645bea8157604780d060d

I tried the cloud storage target with alot of different variations, all reveal the same error. If I try to copy the natality report, it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Daniel

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the error says:
"Table too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a * to shard export." Try switching the destination URI to something like `gs://foo/bar/baz*`

Comment: that was one of the variations for the target location i tried. came up with the same error though...

Answer (score 2):

Specify the file extension along with the pattern. Example

```
gs://foo/bar/baz*.gz in case of GZIP (compressed)

gs://foo/bar/baz*.csv in case of csv (uncompressed)
```

> The foo directory is the bucket name and bar directory can be your
>   date in string format which could be generated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with:

```
bq extract --destination_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON myproject:mydataset.mypartition gs://mybucket/mydataset/mypartition/{*}.json
```